# XFA forms PDF is modified using itextsharp and resulting PDF Gives Extended feature error

Tags: itext

I am trying to set field values programatically by modifying XFA Forms PDF containing 2D Barcode.I am having troble opening rersulting PDF with Regular Adobe Reader. Here is an Error "This document enabled extended features in adobe reader.The document has been changed since it was created and use of extended feature is no longer available.Please contact the author of original version of this document" (Note:-File opens fine with Adobe acrobat)

Following is an example c# code which does this.

```
var reader = new PdfReader(@"c:\abc.pdf");

// System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream(reader, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

var output = new MemoryStream();
var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output, '\0', true);

stamper.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.AllowModifyContents;

stamper.AcroFields.SetField("form1[0].#subform[0].Line1a_FamilyName[0]", "Family Name");

stamper.FormFlattening = false;

stamper.Close();
reader.Close();

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=YourPDF.pdf");
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/6) by iText's author:

> Submitted by Bruno Lowagie on Fri, 12/31/2010 - 16:37
>   After filling out my form, my PDF shows the following message: This document enabled extended features in Adobe Reader. The document has been changed since it was created and use of extended features is no longer available. Please contact the author for the original version of this document. How do I avoid this message?
>   The creator of the form made the document Reader enabled. Reader enabling can only be done using Adobe software. You can avoid this message in two ways:
>    1. Remove the usage rights. This will result in a form that is no longer Reader enabled. For instance: if the creator of the document allowed that the filled out form could be saved locally, this will no longer be possible after removing the usage rights.
>    2. Fill out the form in append mode. This will result in a bigger file size, but Reader enabling will be preserved.
>   For more info, read section 8.7.1 of iText in Action.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your Quick Reply.Yes, I am filling form in append mode only and (reader.RemoveUsageRights()) definately helps with error but in my case 2D barcode becomes unusable.After I fill any form field in PDF the barcode turns into grey image. Any idea why ?

Comment: You might use adobe livecycle server es4 to get barcode reader extension